# having trouble saving a file to MongoDB GridFS using mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, gridfs

Edit: using python 2.7 on Windows 7

I'm having trouble persisting data in a FileField using mongoengine.  The file size before & after saving is drastically different.  Running this:

```
from mongoengine import *
class Test(Document):

   File = FileField()

#connect to my mongodb
connect( 'myDB', host= '192.168.0.3' )

Test.drop_collection()

# write to mongodb GridFS, per the mongoengine documentation: https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/gridfs.html
test = Test()
test.File.put( open( r'c:\temp\owl.jpg', 'r') )
test.save()

#get the Test instance from the db, print out the number of bytes according to mongoengine
test = Test.objects().first()
print test.File.length

#just to make sure we aren't crazy, check the filesize on disk:
print os.path.getsize( r'c:\temp\owl.jpg' )
```

Generates this output:

```
864
145047
```

Any pointers would be appreciated!

- btw, owl.jpg was saved from the following url in case you want to try to reproduce my example exactly:  http://getintobirds.audubon.org/sites/default/files/photos/wildlife_barn_owl.jpg

Comment: What does `Test.File.get().length` return?

Comment: 629

Updated my question to reflect this fact.

Comment: Ok - try without any seeks eg: `test = Test(); test.File.put(open( r'c:\temp\test.pdf')); test.save()`

Comment: Ok, I updated my question to reflect your request. I also made my example more reproducible. Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate on OSX & ubuntu the sizes match.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this on our Ubuntu box.  In the meantime, is there some GridFS config/setting that I may be missing on our mongodb installation?

Comment: I was also unable to replicate this behavior on my Ubuntu machine.  The program behaves as expected on Ubuntu.  It's still a mystery why mongoengine behaves differently on Windows 7 than it does on Ubuntu.

Unfortunately, the target OS for this particular application is Windows..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing:

```
test.File.put( open( r'c:\temp\owl.jpg', 'r') )
```

to:

```
test.File.put( open( r'c:\temp\owl.jpg', 'rb') )
```

Fixes the problem.  Too bad the behavior is inconsistent between OS's.

Comment: Good work, I didn't notice the docs were out of sync with how the tests do it - have updated